# GestureDetector Deprecated Issue

Tags: android, android-mapview, deprecated, android-maps

I have this code

```
itemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);
itemizedOverlay.setGestureDetector(new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetecor()));
```

but `new GestureDetector` is marked as *Deprecated* in Eclipse.

I want to avoid the use of deprecated methods.

How could I fix this problem?

What is the non-deprecated form?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Choose one of the other constructors. There are [five defined constructors on `GestureDetector`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html). Two -- the ones not including a `Context` as the first parameter -- are marked as deprecated. You are using one of those.

Comment: @CommonsWare what should I pass as context?

Comment: @ThEuSeFuL: I would assume that your `Activity` is handy and a likely candidate.

Comment: @CommonsWare I just figured it out and now its working I think. Used getBaseContext()

Answer (score 21):

There are just two deprecated constructors. If you add the context to [GestureDetector(context, listener)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html#GestureDetector%28android.content.Context,%20android.view.GestureDetector.OnGestureListener%29) it's not deprecated.

Comment: how do i get context in class gesture detector

Comment: @Sridhar There are several ways. `Activity` inherits from `Context`, so you can use `this` inside an Activity, or maybe you can use `getApplicationContext()`. See also the comments to @CommonsWare's answer.

Answer (score -2):

1 try add Context to your method: `

itemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);
itemizedOverlay.setGestureDetector(Context context new GestureDetector(new MyGestureDetecor()));`

2 if you already have call to class Context in your method try:

`itemizedOverlay = new MyItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);
itemizedOverlay.setGestureDetector(new GestureDetector(context new MyGestureDetecor()));`