# GestureDetector NullPointerException in "empty" Layout

Tags: android

First of all, my Programm compiles, and starts. But as soon as you tab on the LinearLayout that uses the GestureDetector it throws a NullPointerException.

I have a Activity, in which a Fragment named "OrderFragment" is nested.

```
public class OrderFragment extends Fragment {
View view;
Activity activty;
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.orderfragment, container, false);
    return view;
}


@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    DragList orderContainer = (DragList) view.findViewById(R.id.orderContainer);
    for (int i=0;i<5;++i) {

        final TextView tv = new TextView(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        tv.setTextColor(0x888888);
        tv.setText("wtf");
        orderContainer.addView(tv,new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }

}

}
```

In here, i want to programatically add some TextView into a DragView. This DragView exists in the orderfragment.xml

In the DragView class i try to create some TextViews, the Users can Drag and swap that way. But i struggle to get the Draging to work. Please notice, that the onTouchEvent function is copied word by word from the official android webiste [here](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scale.html)

```
public class DragList extends LinearLayout {


public DragList(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

public DragList(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    //do stuff that was in your original constructor...
}

// The active pointer is the one currently moving our object.
private int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
private int mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
private float mLastTouchX;
private float mLastTouchY;
private GestureDetector mScaleDetector;

public DragList(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.

    mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

    final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev);

    switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(ev);
            final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(ev, pointerIndex);
            final float y = MotionEventCompat.getY(ev, pointerIndex);

            // Remember where we started (for dragging)
            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            // Save the ID of this pointer (for dragging)
            mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, 0);
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            // Find the index of the active pointer and fetch its position
            final int pointerIndex =
                    MotionEventCompat.findPointerIndex(ev, mActivePointerId);

            final float x = MotionEventCompat.getX(ev, pointerIndex);
            final float y = MotionEventCompat.getY(ev, pointerIndex);

            // Calculate the distance moved
            final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
            final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

            float mPosX = dx;
            float mPosY = dy;



            // Remember this touch position for the next move event
            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {

            final int pointerIndex = MotionEventCompat.getActionIndex(ev);
            final int pointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, pointerIndex);

            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {
                // This was our active pointer going up. Choose a new
                // active pointer and adjust accordingly.
                final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                mLastTouchX = MotionEventCompat.getX(ev, newPointerIndex);
                mLastTouchY = MotionEventCompat.getY(ev, newPointerIndex);
                mActivePointerId = MotionEventCompat.getPointerId(ev, newPointerIndex);
            }
            break;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

The Error:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.view.GestureDetector.onTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.jacobusconradi.versuchstestappv20.DragList.onTouchEvent(DragList.java:46)
```

And i can also confirm, that the DragList is visually empty, or NOT there, as I only see the white backgroundcolor given to the Container. When i use Debugging-mode it doesnt throw anything though, when i get to the programatically added TextViews.

THanks for help and cheers

Comment: I cant see the initialization of "mScaleDetector", hence throwing Nullpointert..Plz initialize that variable

Comment: Where are you instantiating mScaleDetector?

Comment: @Satya i do 5 lines above the onTouchEvent(motionEvent ev) line, above the smalles constructor of DragList

Comment: @Nanoc i do 5 lines above the onTouchEvent(motionEvent ev) line, above the smalles constructor of DragList

Comment: Thats a definition, not an instantiation.

Comment: @JacobusConradi: Thats just declaration not the initialization...I think you need to learn the basics before jumping to programming

Comment: @Satya im sorry, its not my mothertounge :D also, everytime i try do initialize it, it says it is depercated :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please  initialize **mScaleDetector** in your `Constructor` section

http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/view/GestureDetector.html

```
mScaleDetector = new GestureDetector(context);
```

Finally

```
    public DragList(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mScaleDetector = new GestureDetector(context);
    }
```

Comment: ok now i am seriously confused. When i do this, it says that it is deprecated, and there is no Option for the GestrureDetector constructor to take a Context, but wants to cast it into a OnGestureListener

Comment: @JacobusConradi http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873708/gesturedetector-deprecated-issue

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya i have the same problem here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62507726/attempt-to-invoke-virtual-method-float-android-view-motionevent-getx-on-exop

Answer (score 0):

Please instantiate your gesture Detector

```
public DragList(Context context) {
    super(context);
    mScaleDetector = new GestureDetector(context);
}
```

Hope this helps.

EDIT

You dont need the gestureDetector for what you are doing, you can just delete it and it should work.

You will need to pass a OnGestureListener if you want the gestureDetector to be able to do something.